# Get device tilt in degrees on each axis in Unity?

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, gyroscope

I'm currently pulling my hair with this issue while developing a game where you can decide on which axis you're going to control.

I have read and studied so much about quanternions, gyros, accelerometers, Kalman and complementary filters... But still I'm lost with this issue:

Axis here are from my enumeration, not gyro axis.

The following code gives the best results so far. 
The problem here is that 
either Y (up/down tilting) or Z axis (lengthwise tilting) aren't working and are somehow mixed, depending a run in device.

X-axis (like steering wheel) is working as expected.

```
    private float GetCurrentTiltByAxis()
{
    float ret = 0;
    if (AccelerometerAxis == Axis.X)
    {
        ret = Input.gyro.attitude.eulerAngles.z;
    }
    else if (AccelerometerAxis == Axis.Y)
    {
#if UNITY_ANDROID
        ret = Input.gyro.attitude.eulerAngles.x;
#else
        ret = Input.gyro.attitude.eulerAngles.y;
#endif
    }
    else if (AccelerometerAxis == Axis.Z)
    {
#if UNITY_ANDROID
        ret = Input.gyro.attitude.eulerAngles.y;
#else
        ret = Input.gyro.attitude.eulerAngles.x;
#endif
    }
    return ret;
}
```

I'm using the latest stable unity and looking to build for iOS and Android.
Orientation is fixed to Landscape left.

All I would need is a function that returns angle of current tilt in specified axis?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Check your If Else on the AccelerometerAxis - You should always get multiple axis rotation unless the device is being held by a robot. Instead of IF ELSE - allow the function to check ALL Axis using multiple IFs...right now I would think ONLY the first if will run because you should get Axis.X every time.

Comment: I will advice you not to use the accelerometer values directly. Have another function that smooths it out then use that new value.This will prevent the GameObject from shaking. I have done something similar before but want to verify if this is what you are trying to do. You just want to steer your GameObject from left to right?

Comment: @Programmer Yes, shaking is definitely happening and  this is something I will implement once I've get value reading from each axis working. For now I have thought of using average, or applying Kalman/Complementary Filter. 
Actually GameObject is only rotating that's why it is why I want to play with angles, since have written my logic to work with angles only.

Comment: @vipasane The solution to your problem requires lots of code to make sure that the thing is not flipping when rotated the wrong way. You needs many if statement to do this. The solution I have uses scale. It scales the 0 to 1 accel values to 0 to 90 degrees value. You can easily modify that. Do you want it?

Comment: @Programmer Yes, all the examples are welcome, since I have tried a lot of things within last six months while getting this thing to work. I would appreciate it very much, thank you.

Comment: Ok. Check back in 5 minutes.